# Table links: designing a concert DB for an artist with several personnel changes

Tags: database, database-design

I'd like to design a fan web site for an artist's concert history, similar to either the one on mikeportnoy.com or forgotten-yesterdays.com.  However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to connect the band personnel to the concert date.  The personnel changes somewhat frequently, so I think they should be in a separate table, which I've named "Lineup".  Here's what I have so far, can someone tell me the best way to join the lineup to a given tour date?  I suppose I can just add DateID to the Lineup table, but I have to believe there's a better way.  Also, the number of people in the band has changed over time; it started as a trio and is now up to 7, but it may go back down or up in the future.

```
Tourdate table
  DateID
  DateYR
  DateMth
  DateDy
  LocID
  VenueID

Lineup table
  ArtistID
  ArtistName
  ArtistInstr

Setlist Table
  DateID
  TrackNo
  SongID

Song table
  SongID
  SongName
  AlbumName
  TrackNo

Venue Table
  VenueID
  VenueName

Location (i.e. City) table
  LocID
  LocName
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following modifications to your initial approach:

```
Tourdate table
    TourdateID
    Date  -- you can split this into its components easily
    LocID
    VenueID
    LineupID
    SetlistID

Artist table
    ArtistID
    ArtistName
    ArtistInstr

Lineup table
    LineupID
    ArtistID

Setlist table
    SetlistID
    SongID
    (you get the date from the Tourdate table and the TrackNo from the Song table)
```

This allows each tour date to have its own lineup and each lineup to have its own set of artists.  Also, venue and location might be the same table; if not, they're certainly going to be linked.